# How to passing Maven Profiles value to Spring Bean XML

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring & Maven, I think my question is simple. But I cannot to figure and setup it. I have Maven POM like below:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <db.driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</db.driverClassName>
            <db.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.148.36.89:1521:mmki</db.url>
            <db.username>APW</db.username>
            <db.password>apw</db.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <db.driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</db.driverClassName>
            <db.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.148.36.88:1521:mmki</db.url>
            <db.username>APW</db.username>
            <db.password>apw</db.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

My question is how I can passing the value from Maven profile to Spring bean property like below:

```
<!-- QA ENVIRONMENT -->
<!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.148.36.89:1521:mmki" />
    <property name="username" value="APW" />
    <property name="password" value="apw" />
</bean> -->

<!-- PRD ENVIRONMENT -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.148.36.88:1521:mmki" />
    <property name="username" value="APW" />
    <property name="password" value="apw" />
</bean>
```

I'm so dumb for this question, but please everyone to answer and explain with the simple method.

Many thanks.

Comment: You should use spring-boot profiles instead of Maven profiles.

Answer (score 1):

First:

Do not write user and pass at pom.xml file

Second:

1. You can have one applicationContext for each environment like applicationContext-prod.xml and applicationContext-qa.xml
2. On your pom.xml you can have one property for each profile like:

pom.xml

```
<profile>
    <id>qa</id>
    <properties>
       <appContext>classpath:applicationContext-qa.xml</appContext>
       ...
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <properties>
        <appContext>classpath:applicationContext-prod.xml</appContext>
        ...
    </properties>
</profile>
```

In web.xml you can write you context param like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>${appContext}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you write your passwords in the applicationContext files you do not need anything else. But, for security reasons I recommend you as **best practice** write your sensible environment values at external properties file:

3. You can have multiple *.properties on /etc/app
   (production.properties and qa.properties)

And finally, on your applicationContext-prod.xml you can have your propertyConfigurer like:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
       <value>file:/etc/app/production.properties</value>
   </property>
</bean>

....

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        ....
        <property name="password">
            <value>${db.password}</value>
```

And on your applicationContext-qa.xml you can have your propertyConfigurer like:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
       <value>file:/etc/app/qa.properties</value>
   </property>
</bean>
...
```

Obviously on your /etc/app/production.properties you have to write:

```
db.password=prodpass
```

Finally, on your /etc/app/qa.properties you have to write:

```
db.password=qapass
```

Comment: Hi Sergio, thanks for your explanation. I will try as your reference.